# Single item list based off enumerate

Tags: enumitem

I have a successful `questions` environment that is based off of the `enumerate` environment using the `enumitem` package.  It correctly continues numbering from the previous `questions` environments.

What I want is a `question` environment that mimics exactly the behavior of a `questions` environment with a single item.  The following is my attempt, which I hoped would produce labels 1,2,3,4,5.  Instead it produces labels 1,1,2,3,3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions,1]{label=\arabic*.,resume}
\newenvironment{question}{\begin{questions} \item }{\end{questions}}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
    One
\end{question}
\begin{questions}
    \item Two
\end{questions}
\begin{questions}
    \item Three
\end{questions}
\begin{question}
    Four
\end{question}
\begin{question}
    Five
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

How would I create a `question` environment (a single item list) that has compatible label numbering with the `questions` environment?

Comment: Create a new counter `\newcounter{exer}` and use it in an environment *question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but when you use `resume` a list you need to specify a name for what you want to resume. So, in the first instance you specify the name via `series=MyQuestion`, and then for subsequent list items you resume it via `resume=MyQuestion`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions,1]{label=\arabic*.,resume=MyQuestion}
\newenvironment{question}{\begin{questions}[series=MyQuestion] \item }{\end{questions}}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
    One
\end{question}
\begin{questions}
    \item Two
\end{questions}
\begin{questions}
    \item Three
\end{questions}
\begin{question}
    Four
\end{question}
\begin{question}
    Five
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, but I need this to work regardless of whether a `question` or `questions` environment came first.  This solution breaks if a `questions` comes first and a `question` follows.

Comment: @HansParshall: From your question it is not clear to me exactly what you want to do. What is the intended difference between a `question` and `questions` environment. Please update your question to include this information and update the test case so that it tests all your use scenarios.

Comment: The solution seems to be to set `resume=MyQuestion` in both question and questions.